# JQuery load involved PHP script, no response in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, load

Helo,

The following code loads a some google map directions in. For some reason Firefox returns nothing. Firebug does not report any errors, however the line action turns read and response reads nothing. I've built my own version that adds a PHP file in the middle to no avail.

Why does it not work on firefox.

```
$('#directionex .dirscroll').load('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=' + start + '&destination=' + end + '&sensor=false')
```

Any idea why this does not work.

Marvellous,

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Is the line actually missing a `;` on the end or is it just missing from the copy/paste? Because FF can be quite particular about this in places that other browsers aren't...

Comment: is that maybe because you're making an ajax call to a different domain?

Comment: I usually find Ffx to be quite forgiving, but @DaveRandom is right: proper js syntax would have a `;` at the end.
I would put my money on @stratton about the ajax load from different domain.

Comment: you also might try www.jslint.com to validate/troubleshoot your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example doesn't work for me in any browser. The issue is likely to do with the same origin policy. You can't load arbitrary resources from any domain into your page. I would suggest checking out the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/).

Comment: You are correct. I have it working now by first putting all pages online and secondly removing the http://..... and putting a more direct url in relation to where the PHP file lies in relation to mine so ../directions.php?start=.... and loading in the google data into that PHP file via XML. This works but for testing purposes it would be much nicer if JQuery load would load in the php file of our server.